# Laravel 5 auth guard with RESTful API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I have a solution developed which uses `Laravel 5`. It's not entirely developed on laravel.

API layer resides on another project and only the web layer uses laravel.

So far I have been storing the auth details in session and using basic way to handle authenticated users.

Now I have been trying to upgrade the web app structure into `laravel frontend & backend` module. The difficulty that I'm facing is to use the `providers` & `guards` concept as it doesn't interact with the database directly.

So far what I have done is the controller I'm checking user's role and is authenticated using `$_Session`.

It would be really helpful if one could enlighten me on using RESTful API with Laravel Auth guards.

## Registration controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

require_once dirname(__DIR__, 3) . '/web_api/DependencyManager.php';

use DBHandlers;
use Facebook;
use Google;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use SessionManager;
use Session;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function mRegister($ref = null)
    {
        $session = new SessionManager();
        $db = new DBHandlers();


        isset($ref) && $ref == 'google' ? $registered_via_google = true : $registered_via_fb = true;

        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            if (isset($ref)) {
                if (strcmp($ref, "facebook") == 0) {
                    $registered_via_fb = true;
                } else {
                    $registered_via_google = true;
                }
            }
        }


        if (isset($registered_via_fb) && $registered_via_fb) {
            //  echo 'Facebook';
            try {
                $fb = new Facebook();
                $fb->mProcess();
                //   echo $_GET['code'];
                //     print_r($fb->getAcessToken());
                $fb_access_token = (string)$fb->getAcessToken();
                //  echo $fb_access_token;
                if (isset($fb_access_token) && $fb_access_token != '' && !empty($fb_access_token)) {
                    $result = $db->mFBLogin($fb_access_token);
                    $session->LogUserIn($result);

                } else {
                    $registration_error = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $registration_error = true;
            }

        } 

    }

    public function mLogout()
    {
        Session::flush();
        redirect()->route('index')->send();
        die();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be to read through the `Passport` documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport

It may not be what you're using, but it will give you a good idea of how Laravel handles authentication and authorization through an API.

The default auth guard in Laravel uses `session` but often times restful APIs are stateless so you'll need to manage an authentication token. This is done with using the `auth:api` middleware.

Passport is an excellent package for this, being a fully fledged OAuth2 server, then for JWT I would recommend:

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Update:

Do you have a `users` table in the Laravel app which you can associated the api login with? If so, then in your situation, you can use the `web` guard and `session` driver. After you have authenticated and receive a response, query for the user and then manually log them in to Laravel:

```
// use the same email address here they used to login to the api.
$user = User::where('email', 'someone@somewhere.com')->first();
auth()->login($user);
```

You'd use the `web` middleware group to manage authorizing requests from then on out.

If a custom solution is what you really need, the Laravel documentation has a good example how to implement your own:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: Please note I'm not looking for api package, and not even considering to migrate the API layer.

Comment: Noted, just some good material to read about different approaches to API auth. Can you post the controller code where you authenticate the user with `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Please let me brief my problem, I'm looking for a solution to create auth guards from api response, I'm not looking forward to use tokens to authenticate the apis.

Please find the updated query with the controller attached

Comment: Sorry but I am not using any database logic. regarding custom guard, won't it be easier if I could just initialise or assign the role or auth user when registration is complete?